# Docker gives strange permissions to self-created mountpoints

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, acl

I'm using ACLs to ensure to have write access from the host to the volumes. I have a `docker-compose.yml` where for example MySQL and MongoDB have there data directories in Docker volumes. It's not relevant what's behind these volumes. It even happens to empty unused container folders.

If the local folder of the volume pair doesn't exist, Docker creates it and sets some strange permissions. If the folder was already there, the permission is normal as expected.

In the root of the project I set ACLs:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:mri:rwX .
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:mri:rwX .
```

For example the docker-compose.yml contains:

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:3.0
  volumes:
    - ./docker/var/mongo:/data/db
```

When I start the container and Docker creates the mongo directory it crashes the permissions and I get this:

```
$ getfacl docker/var/mongo
# file: docker/var/mongo
# owner: 999
# group: root
user::rwx
user:mri:rwx            #effective:r-x
group::rwx              #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:mri:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

At this point I don't have write access anymore.

This doesn't happen if the folder exists before. And if I run the setfacl commands again, I do have access again. But in my automated workflow this is not possible and it would not be a real solution.

Why does this happen and how to let Docker create this folder without changing the permissions?

Comment: We have this issue on host machine with Ubuntu 16 and on the other machine with Ubuntu 18 the same commands are working properly (effective permissions are `rwx`). We're struggling with this since yesterday. We even added `setfacl -dRm m:rwx` and still when container starts we get effective `r-x` on directories when we set `rwx` :(

Comment: [Running Docker Containers as Current Host User](https://jtreminio.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-current-host-user/)